# Convolution outputs immense values instead of 0-1 range

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, generative-adversarial-network

I am developing a GAN that operates on 2 channels of an image.
The network is fed with the image layers data rescaled in a range 0-1.

It is composed roughly as following (i do not have a graphical representation, sorry)

1. `concatenate(multiply(noise_a, l_channel), multiply(noise_b, l_channel))`
2. n x (`(Conv2D with relu activation)` + `batchnorm`)

the step 1 produces a 2 layers that are then fed to the following conv2D steps

i checked that everything passed as an input (noise, image channels) is rescaled in the range 0-1, but the output of the network produces enormous values, (on the -128 -> 1000+ range).

I'd expect the output to be in the range 0-1 (that will later be rescaled in a range -128,+127).

**The questions**

1. am i wrong in the assumption that the output range should be 0-1  ?
2. could you point me to what else to check or correct to make this happen ?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: There's no reason for the output range to be [0,1]. The convolution kernel could have very large weights.

Comment: the convolution sums over the individual cell products (as opposed to averaging), doesn't it ? How many cells do you have in your convolution filter ?

Comment: Sunreef thank you for your answer,  is there a common approach in this case? rescale after the output? 

@AndreHolzner it's a 3x3 kernel, stride 1, padding same

Comment: use a sigmoid funtion in the end